# java.lang.VerifyError: Verifier rejected class - failed to verify

Tags: java, android, protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-java

I am using `protobuf` to auto-generate my API services, in [`gRPC`](https://grpc.io/docs/tutorials/basic/android.html) technology, in my android client. It's been months since i have been working on it without a problem. Now all of a sudden, the AndroidRuntime Verifier is rejecting one of the auto-generated methods of my API.

---

**Here is the stacktrace:**

```
com.company.companyplayer E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                        Process: com.company.companyplayer, PID: 18181
                                        java.lang.VerifyError: Verifier rejected class company.v1.PlayerEarningsPageDataResponse: void company.v1.PlayerEarningsPageDataResponse.mergeNextDepositDate(com.google.protobuf.Timestamp) failed to verify: void company.v1.PlayerEarningsPageDataResponse.mergeNextDepositDate(com.google.protobuf.Timestamp): [0x26] register v5 has type Precise Reference: com.google.protobuf.Timestamp but expected Reference: com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLiteVerifier rejected class company.v1.PlayerEarningsPageDataResponse: java.lang.Object company.v1.PlayerEarningsPageDataResponse.dynamicMethod(com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite$MethodToInvoke, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object) failed to verify: java.lang.Object company.v1.PlayerEarningsPageDataResponse.dynamicMethod(com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite$MethodToInvoke, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object): [0x16E] register v8 has type Precise Reference: com.google.protobuf.Timestamp but expected Reference: com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite (declaration of 'company.v1.PlayerEarningsPageDataResponse' appears in /data/app/com.company.companyplayer-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk)
                                            at company.v1.PlayerEarningsPageDataResponse.getDefaultInstance(PlayerEarningsPageDataResponse.java:0)
                                            at company.v1.APIGrpc.<clinit>(APIGrpc.java:47)
                                            at company.v1.APIGrpc.newStub(APIGrpc.java:0)
                                            at com.company.companyplayer.backend.Client.getAuthAsyncStub(Client.java:103)
                                            at com.company.companyplayer.backend.Client.playerLogin(Client.java:119)
                                            at com.company.companyplayer.ui.activity.LoginActivity.loginAndGoToMainActivity(LoginActivity.java:202)
                                            at com.company.companyplayer.ui.activity.LoginActivity.onActivityResult(LoginActivity.java:127)
                                            at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6935)
                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4086)
                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4133)
                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(ActivityThread.java)
                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1534)
                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6121)
                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889)
                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)
```

---

**The following (solutions suggested on similar SO posts) did not work:**

- Clean and re-build (even tried cleaning manually)
- Invalidate Caches & Restart IDE
- Regenerate API definition from proto

---

**Also, here is the auto-generated method pointed out in the stacktrace:**

```
  private void mergeNextDepositDate(com.google.protobuf.Timestamp value) {
    if (nextDepositDate_ != null && nextDepositDate_ != com.google.protobuf.Timestamp.getDefaultInstance()) {
      nextDepositDate_ = com.google.protobuf.Timestamp.newBuilder(nextDepositDate_).mergeFrom(value).buildPartial();
    } else {
      nextDepositDate_ = value;
    } 
  }
```

It can be seen that the method is neither very lengthy, nor takes too many parameters; somethings that have been said be common causes for this error.

---

**Following is the build.gradle for my app:** (Nothing has been changed in the gradle since the last time that all of this was working fine)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.protobuf'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.company.companyplayer"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 5
        versionName "0.1"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }
}

protobuf {
    protoc {
        artifact = 'com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.2.0'
    }
    plugins {
        javalite {
            artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc-gen-javalite:3.0.0"
        }
        grpc {
            artifact = 'io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.3.0'
        }
    }
    generateProtoTasks {
        all().each { task ->
            task.plugins {
                javalite {}
                grpc {
                    // Options added to --grpc_out
                    option 'lite'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    /* android support libraries */
    compile 'com.google.android:flexbox:0.2.7'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:11.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4.4'
    compile 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.1'
    compile 'io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:1.3.0'
    compile 'io.grpc:grpc-protobuf-lite:1.3.0'
    compile 'io.grpc:grpc-stub:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:account-kit-sdk:4.22.0'
    compile 'javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2'
    compile 'com.google.api.grpc:googleapis-common-protos:0.0.3' // This is for importing "google/api/annotations.proto" in our proto file
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestCompile 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.1'
    protobuf 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

---

**UPDATE:** The error has definitely something to do with `google.protobuf.Timestamp`. Here is the [**link to an MWE**](https://github.com/abdulwasae/google.protobuf.timestamp-java.lang.VerifyError) that reproduces this problem.

Comment: Is it possible that you are getting full protobuf as a dependency accidentally? I assume you want to use protobuf lite. Run `./gradlew dependencies` and make sure you only have com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite dependencies, not com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java

Comment: @EricAnderson There are a number of protobuf related entries in my gradle, most of which a 'lite'. Since i am unsure about which one it is that you are talking about, i am adding my build.gradle to the question above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing lite and full protobuf.

You can't have a compile or runtime dependency on `googleapis-common-protos`, as it is generated code for full protobuf, which does not work with lite protobuf. It also brings in a dependency to `protobuf-java`, which when mixed with `protobuf-lite` will cause duplicate classes. Instead of compile dependency, use a protobuf dependency to have the protobuf gradle plugin generate the code from `.proto`s included in the JAR.

You also don't have any dependency on `protobuf-lite` currently, so without the common protos dependency you would get compile failures. Common protos is also bringing in the `grpc-protobuf-lite` dependency that is needed. I'd suggest adding a compile time dependency on `io.grpc:grpc-protobuf-lite:1.3.0` which will also bring in `protobuf-lite`.

So in short, make these changes to the project and it compiles:

```
diff --git a/app/build.gradle b/app/build.gradle
index 8f606bb..2fb997b 100644
--- a/app/build.gradle
+++ b/app/build.gradle
@@ -62,7 +62,8 @@ dependencies {
     compile 'javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2'
     compile 'io.grpc:grpc-stub:1.3.0'
     compile 'io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:1.3.0'
+    compile 'io.grpc:grpc-protobuf-lite:1.3.0'

-    compile 'com.google.api.grpc:googleapis-common-protos:0.0.3'
+    protobuf 'com.google.api.grpc:googleapis-common-protos:0.0.3'
     protobuf 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.1.0'
 }
```